# What do you call a name that reflects the person's characteristics?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, names

How to translate the Russian phrase 'говорящая фамилия'? It's literally translated as "speaking surname" and refers to last names that reflect the person's quality. For example, if a short man is named "John Little" the last name is a "speaking surname", in Russian terms. It (the adjective) can be used not only with surnames, with any names, basically (of inanimate things as well).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not as easily understandable as the Russian phrase, but there's a word *euonym*

> a name well suited to the person, place, or thing named

(source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/euonym))

The name is derived from ancient Greek 'eu' meaning 'good' and the 'onym' suffix is often used to denote some kind of word (synonym, homonym).

[Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/aptronym) lists *aptronym* / *aptonym*:

> A person's name that is regarded as amusingly appropriate to their occupation.
> *‘he began collecting aptronyms when he saw an ad for a flower shop operated by Flora Gardner’*

It's derived from the word 'apt' meaning 'appropriate'.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aptronym) has a nice list of English aptronyms.

Comment: And there is the related concept of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominative_determinism where people choose an occupation suited to their name.

Comment: These are uncommon words, are they?

Comment: Yes, they are quite uncommon.

Comment: In everyday speech I would just say the person was 'aptly named', or 'had the appropriate name of ...'.